# Arrays in swift purposes

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

What is the purpose of ​`​shoppingList​[​1​] = ​"bottle of water"` code shown below?

It overrides shoppingList 1+1nd array. Is it true?

```
“​var​ ​shoppingList​ = [​"catfish"​, ​"water"​, ​"tulips"​, ​"blue paint"​]
​shoppingList​[​1​] = ​"bottle of water"
​ 
​var​ ​occupations​ = [
​    ​"Malcolm"​: ​"Captain"​,
​    ​"Kaylee"​: ​"Mechanic"​,
​]
​occupations​[​"Jayne"​] = ​"Public Relations”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/tr/jEUH0.l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It replaces "water" by "bottle of water". The index of arrays starts at 0.

Answer (score 2):

`​shoppingList​[​1​]` will replace what is in the array `shoppingList` at index **1**. So it will replace "water" with "bottle of water"